# Group the result by user who completed the items using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I want to group the result at the end by using multiple Join.

There is three lists `User`, `Item`, and `ItemCompleted`:

**UserList:**

```
//users
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

//output
[{
    "Id": 2154,
    "Name": "Joanne"
}, {
    "Id": 2207,
    "Name": "Kylie"
}, {
    "Id": 2159,
    "Name": "Madeleine"
},{
    "Id": 2160,
    "Name": "Mat"
}]
```

**Item List**

```
//items
public class Item
{
    public string Item { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

//output
[{
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "Item 1"
}, {
    "Id": 2,
    "Name": "Item 2"
}, {
    "Id": 3,
    "Name": "Item 3"
},{
    "Id": 291,
    "Name": "Item 291"
},{
    "Id": 288,
    "Name": "Item 288"
},{
    "Id": 290,
    "Name": "Item 290"
}]
```

]

**Item Completed List**

```
//completedItems
public class ItemCompleted
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int ModuleId { get; set; }
    public string Event { get;set; }
}

//output
[{
    "UserId": 2154,
    "ModuleId": 1,
    "Event": "Lesson"
}, {
    "UserId": 2154,
    "ModuleId": 2,
    "Event": "Interactive Content"
}, {
    "UserId": 2207,
    "ModuleId": 3,
    "Event": "Interactive Content"
}, {
    "UserId": 2159,
    "ModuleId": 2,
    "Event": "Interactive Content"
}, {
    "UserId": 2207,
    "ModuleId": 2,
    "Event": "Interactive Content",
}, {
    "UserId": 2159,
    "ModuleId": 1,
    "Event": "Lesson"
}, {
    "UserId": 2207,
    "ModuleId": 1,
    "Event": "Lesson"
}]
```

The left join with `Item` and `CompletedItems` is applied and the List of CompletedItem are listed:

```
var itemsResult = from item in items
                  join completed in completedItems on item.Id equals completed.ModuleId into cmpltItem
                  from ct in cmpltItem.DefaultIfEmpty()
                  select new CompletedItem()
                  {
                      ModuleId = item.Id,
                      ItemType = ct?.Event,
                      Item = item.Activity,
                      UserId = ct?.UserId
                  };
```

If the item is not completed by any user:

```
[{
    "ModuleId": 291,
    "Item": "Item 291",
    "ItemType": null,
    "UserId": null
}, {
    "ModuleId": 288,
    "Item": "Item  288",
    "ItemType": null,
    "UserId": null
}, {
    "ModuleId": 290,
    "Item": "Item  290",
    "ItemType": null,
    "UserId": null
}]
```

Now I want to group the number of items completed by Username:

```
var groupedUserbyItem = users
                     .Select(c => new UserCompletedItem
                     {
                         Name = c.Name,
                         UserId = c.Id,
                         CompletedItems = itemsResult.Where(x => x.UserId == c.Id)
                             .Select(t => new CompletedItem { }).ToList()
                     })
                      .ToList();
```

**UserCompletedItem**

```
public class UserCompletedItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<CompletedItem> CompletedItems { get; set; }
}

public class CompletedItem
{
    public int? ModuleId { get; set; }
    public string Item { get; set; }
    public string ItemType { get; set; }
    public int? UserId { get; set; }
}
```

But I am stuck in the grouping of the items with the user.

Desired Output: If the user completed one item, two items, or no item.

```
[{
        "UserId": 2154,
        "Name": "Joanne",
        "CompletedItems": [{
                "id": 1,
                "Item": "Item 1",
                "ItemType": "Lesson"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "Item": "Item 2",
                "ItemType": "Interactive Content"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "UserId": 2160,
        "Name": "Mat",
        "CompletedItems": []
    },
    {
        "UserId": 2159,
        "Name": "Madeleine",
        "CompletedItems": [{
            "id": 2,
            "Item": "Item 2",
            "ItemType": "Interactive Content"
        }, {
            "id": 1,
            "Item": "Item 1",
            "Event": "Lesson"
        }]
    },
    {
        "UserId": 2207,
        "Name": "Madeleine",
        "CompletedItems": [{
            "id": 3,
            "Item": "Item 3",
            "ItemType": "Interactive Content"
        }, {
            "id": 2,
            "Item": "Item 2",
            "ItemType": "Interactive Content"
        }, {
            "id": 1,
            "Item": "Item 1",
            "Event": "Lesson"
        }]
    }
]
```

Comment: Could you include a desired output example? The example should at least contain a user that completed at least one item, a user that did not complete any item and an item that was not completed by any user. You will probably need more than one user with completed items in order to demonstrate your desired output order

Comment: @grek40 i have updated the post.

Comment: Sounds like (logically speaking) `User LEFT JOIN (CompletedItems JOIN Item) GROUP BY User`. I don't see any need to have a list where not-completed items are included as an intermediate step.

Comment: @grek40 yeah i also thought same! but because I was confused about using three joins in a same linq query.

Comment: @aakash the test sample, used in *Item Completed List* not match the left join, for me : if a based on : 2154 have 2 items, 2207 : 3 items and 2159 have one item? *CompletionTime* because not exist in the sample

Comment: Yea... as far as I can tell, the "Desired Output" is currently NOT the result of the provided example inputs.

Comment: @aakash i don't see *CompletionTime* also in ``ItemCompleted`` and the test based on, to differentiate between completed an not completed items.

Comment: @Sajid yes there will be completion time in main output but to keep the sample short I have omitted that.

Comment: @aakash i'm with you for shirt sample, the no completed items OK for me, but the expected result no: user 2154 OK, 2207 why don't have items?, he has moduldId 1,2,3 that match item Id, 2159 why linked to moduleID 3 it's 1 and 2? tell if i'm not understanding correctly.

Comment: yeah i have changed the desired output

Answer (score 1):

You could use two queries, like the following code :

1 - Get completed items :

```
var query1 = (from itemCompleted in itemCompleteds
              join item in items on itemCompleted.ModuleId equals item.Id
              select new
              {
                 UserId = itemCompleted.UserId, 
                 ModuleId = item.Id, 
                 Item = item.Name, 
                 ItemType = itemCompleted.Event 
              })
              .Distinct()
              .ToList();
```

2 - Group completed item by user and build `UserCompletedItem`:

```
var finalResult = (from user in users
                   join itemCompleted in query1 on user.Id equals itemCompleted.UserId into leftResults
                   from leftedResult in leftResults.DefaultIfEmpty()
                   group leftedResult by new { user.Id, user.Name } into grp
                   select new UserCompletedItem
                   {
                       UserId = grp.Key.Id,
                       Name = grp.Key.Name,
                       CompletedItems = grp
                       .Where(x => x != null)
                       .Select(x => new CompletedItem
                       {
                           ModuleId = x.ModuleId,
                           Item = x.Item,
                           ItemType = x.ItemType
                       }).ToList()
                   }).ToList();
```

I hope you find this helpful.

Comment: Just one thing more, what if the item is duplicate and needs to return only one item in `CompletedItems`?

Comment: @aakash let me check

Comment: @aakash if item is duplicated, in query1, you can select anonymous object and use distinct and construct ``UserCompletedItem`` in the second query.